# WPF window resizing - no preview / show rubber band

Tags: wpf, directx, resize, direct3d

Is there a way to force a WPF window to use a rubber band (no live preview of contents during resize) when resizing?

I realize this is usually a user preference on Windows but my application uses D3D windows and there is significant flicker when resizing (particularly from the top left corner outward).

--

I should have mentioned I am using DX10 via SlimDX. I haven't found a way to use D3DImage with DX10. Is this possible?

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using DX10 via SlimDX. I haven't found a way to use D3DImage with DX10. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The best option, in this case, is to use the [D3DImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx) class to present your DX content within WPF.  This allows you to have smooth scaling Direct3D content within WPF - with no flickering.  In addition, this provides much more complex compositing options, since airspace is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Reed, D3DImage class has what you need. I don't think there is a way otherwise to prevent redraw when resizing save for overloading a heck of a lot of window events in an ugly way.